How can I set up an access point on Linux and still be connected to the internet?
I need to use a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as an access point, to connect an Ethernet-only device to the Internet, and to be able to ssh into it from the network.
The laptop does not have WiFi access to the internet, but should connect using USB tethering. My work PC should connect to the laptop using WiFi, so that it can both access the Internet and the device.
What I thought would be nice to have is something like this:
 +--------------------+          +--------------------------+           +-------------------+
 |                    |          |                          |           |                   |
 |                    |    USB   |                          |  Eth      |     Device to     |
 |   Mobile phone     o----------o       Old laptop         +-----------+     connect       |
 |   (with internet)  |          |                          |           |                   |
 |                    |          |                          |           |                   |
 +--------------------+          +--------------------------+           +-------------------+
                                             -
                                             - WiFi
                                             -
                                             -
                                 +--------------------------+
                                 |                          |
                                 |                          |
                                 |        Work PC           |
                                 |                          |
                                 |                          |
                                 +--------------------------+

The mobile phone should provide Internet to all three devices, and the work PC should be able to ssh into the other two.
I mostly successfully managed to accomplish this by setting up an access point on the laptop using hostapd, and by bridging all three interfaces together using a network bridge (using ip link set dev <interface> master br0).
However, now the laptop cannot connect to the net, as all of its interfaces are used by other devices. Moreover, I can't see the other devices in my ARP table from the work PC, I assume this is because some filtering has been done by either the laptop or the phone.
I heard that this is usually resolved by creating one or two virtual interfaces, however I tried and now it seems like my work PC cannot connect to the internet anymore. I suspect it is because not all NICs support this, and apparently mine does not.
So, how can I make the laptop connect to the network it is hosting too? Alternatively, how should I set up this configuration? Thanks!
Current config:
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:
interface=wlp2s0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=acer-SAN13254
country_code=IT
hw_mode=g
channel=6
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=-1
fragm_threshold=-1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=#####################
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP


All interfaces? You said you were only bridging Wi-Fi and Ethernet – where is the interface created by USB tethering, though?

@u1686_grawity it is created when USB tethering is activated, I manually add it to the bridge using ip link set <usb_interface> master br0. In the end, all three are inserted in the bridge

You should not add the usb interface as a bridge port: it's intended to be routing as the WAN interface, and is probably auto-configured by the phone (eg: with DHCP). Once set as bridge port nothing works anymore.

And whatever you do, such as the command used in the comment, better add it in the question ( edit it), rather than comment.

@A.B sorry, I didn't add it because I assumed it was the only way to do it. Regarding the first comment, could you elaborate on what is the preferred method? Should I set up a NAT, and IP forwarding (basically, turning the PC into a full router)? Note that by adding the USB interface to the bridge internet works, and I'm able to ssh into the device, it uses the DHCP provided by the phone. However, I can't ping certain connections, for example I can't ping the work PC from the device.


However, now the laptop cannot connect to the net, as all of its interfaces are used by other devices

With Linux bridges, the br0 interface itself acts as not only the bridge, but also as the host OS "port" into the bridge. So instead of the IP address being configured on usb0 for USB tethering, the exact same IP address (and default gateway, etc) now needs to be configured on br0 for the Old PC to have Internet access.
That is, you need to run the DHCP client on br0.
Bridging might simply not work 100% well with USB tethering, though – although the link emulates an Ethernet interface over USB, it won't necessarily behave the same; e.g. the phone may expect only one device (only one MAC address) or it might issue only one IP address.
So it might be possible that you need to bridge only eth0 and wlan0, but not the USB tethering interface; instead, if the work PC needs Internet access, the "Old PC" would need to route between USB and the bridge. That's a bit more work, as you need to set up iptables (instructions for doing both are fairly generic and often found alongside the "set up an AP" instructions) as well as some DHCP server on br0, but it might be the more reliable option.

Moreover, I can't see the other devices in my ARP table from the work PC, I assume this is because some filtering has been done by either the laptop or the phone.

The ARP table will only have devices that the PC actively communicates with; it is a cache of recent IPv4-to-MAC address lookup results. If the Work PC has not contacted the Device via IPv4 yet, then there would have been no reason for it to do an ARP query and therefore nothing that would be cached in the ARP table.
The phone is not in a position to do much filtering – assuming it issues IP configuration that puts all devices in the same network/subnet (which is the simplest and most likely setup), then devices in the same subnet communicate directly across the bridge without any involvement of the router.
